# ArrayList Calculate Average by dropping Smallest

Tags: java, arraylist, average

I have two problems with my code. 1) It's not giving me the right average when I add values to my arraylist so I know my condition in my for loop is off and 2) It's not showing all the numbers in my arrayList. It specifically doesn't show the 0th integer.

Here is my code:

```
public class CalcAvgDropSmallest {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
       int lowNum = 0;  // # of the lowest numbers to be dropped
       double average;  // calcuates the mean of the sum and the lowest numbers dropped
       ArrayList<Double> inputs= getALInfo();
       lowNum = getLowestnum();
       average = calculateAvg(inputs, lowNum);
       getAvg(inputs, lowNum, average);

    }

    public static ArrayList<Double> getALInfo() {
        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

        // Read Inputs
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Please enter 5 - 10 integers, Q to quit: ");         
          Double vals = in.nextDouble();

         while (in.hasNextDouble())
            {
               inputs.add(in.nextDouble());
            }             

        return inputs;     
    }   

    public static int getLowestnum() {        
        int lowNum = 0;

        // Reads Input value for # of lowest values dropped

        System.out.println("How many of the lowest values should be dropped?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        lowNum = in.nextInt();

        return lowNum;

    }

    public static double calculateAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputs, int lowNum) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;                
        int i = 0;
        // Calcuates the average of the array list with the lowest numbers dropped

        for (i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) 
        {
            if (inputs.get(i) > lowNum) {
                sum = sum + inputs.get(i);
            }
        }
        average = (sum / inputs.size());        

       return average;
    }

    public static void getAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputs,int n, double average) {
       // It's adding all the values and dividing by the size of it, which is a problem
       // Also, it's not showing the 0th integer aand just straight to the 1st integer
      System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + inputs + " except the lowest " +n+ " is " +average);  
    }
}
```

Comment: You're throwing away the first double entered!

Comment: Here: `Double vals = in.nextDouble();`. Don't do that, don't ignore that first entry. You put in in vals, but never put it in your ArrayList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please program to the `List` interface (instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type). Second, you should make sure you add each value you read to your `List`. Then, make sure you read the terminating value (and discard it); otherwise it will be pending in the buffer. Finally, I would pass the `Scanner` into the methods (instead of re-declaring it locally). Like,

```
public static List<Double> getALInfo(Scanner in) {
    List<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 - 10 integers, Q to quit: ");
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        inputs.add(in.nextDouble());
    }
    in.next();
    return inputs;
}
```

You could simplify `getLowestnum` like

```
public static int getLowestnum(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("How many of the lowest values should be dropped?");
    return in.nextInt();
}
```

Then your `calculateAvg` should sort the `List` and take a `subList` (discarding `lowNum` values) and finally return the average. Something like,

```
public static double calculateAvg(List<Double> inputs, int lowNum) {
    Collections.sort(inputs);
    return inputs.subList(lowNum, inputs.size()).stream()
            .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
}
```

And then `main` to complete the example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Double> inputs = getALInfo(in);
    int lowNum = getLowestnum(in);
    double average = calculateAvg(inputs, lowNum);
    System.out.printf("%.2f%n", average);
}
```